# Can you do a pointer to a class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

**Note: I do not mean a pointer to an OBJECT or INSTANCE I mean a pointer to a CLASS**

I put this at the top because I know if I don't people will tell me that I can do

```cpp
class MyClass;
MyClass* pointerToMyClass = new MyClass(); // Ta-da! pointer to class!
```

This is not what I am looking for.  I would like to make a pointer to a class type itself, kind of like a function pointer, but for a class.

To make it more clear what I am asking, here is some code that roughly demonstrates what I am looking for.

```cpp
class MyClass; // real Class
class MyDerived : public MyClass; // derived class

class * ClassPointer = &MyClass; // pointer to my class
MyClass * instanceOfPointer = new ClassPointer(); // now makes an instance of MyClass

ClassPointer = &MyDerived; // pointer to derived class
MyClass * instance2 = new ClassPointer(); // now makes an instance of DerivedClass
```

So kind of like a typedef, but more dynamic.

I would also want be able to make a vector of class pointers.  Currently, I am hacking in the behavior I need with a class function `clone()` that returns a new pointer to the base class, but I don't particularly like this approach.

Is there anything like this possible in C++?

Edit: 
The current problem I am using this for is a polymorphic network protocol. 
There is a base packet class:

```cpp
class packet{
    int id=0;
    virtual packet* read(); // read packet type into id
    virtual packet* clone(){ return new packet(); }
};
```

then multiple derived packets:

```cpp
class packet1 : public packet{
    int id=1
    packet* read(); // do packet specific reading
    packet * clone(){ return new packet1(); }
};

class packet2 : public packet{
    int id=2
    packet* read(); // do packet specific reading
    packet * clone(){ return new packet21(); }
};

class packet3 : public packet{
    int id=3
    packet* read(); // do packet specific reading
    packet * clone(){ return new packet3(); }
};
```

then to read a packet all you have to do is

```cpp
packet* array[] = { new packet(), new packet1(), new packet2(), new packet3() }; // array of packets, this should be class* if possible
packet type = packet();
type.read(); // read type from network
packet* data = array[type.id].clone(); // pick derived class based on type
data->read(); // read specific packet from network
```

The `packet*[]` would be replaced with a `class*[]` to avoid having to use `clone()`.

This is a simplified but workable example.

Comment: No. It is not possible. But you could explain the problem you have and ask for possible design solution. Though, there are some trouble some limitations in C++ because reflection is missing and template meta-programming is difficult and unreadable.

Comment: That doesn't even make sense. Think of how you'd use this, in a language that is hard typed. What you probably want to take a look at are templates.

Comment: Can you explain what about the `clone` method you don't like so we know what kind of solution you would like? Is it the requirement to have an instance of the class? (Because, if so, that can be easily worked around.)

Comment: You could play around with `std::decltype` but that just seems unpractical. Templates are the way to do this.

Comment: There you are, one use case. and no templates would not work for this particular thing, templates are for if you have an algorithm you want to work with many types of data, this is an entirely different situation.

Comment: Since the only thing you need to do is default-construct it, you can just use a static function. (Which is a good thing because how can be sure that every derived class has a public default constructor?) `template<typename T> T* make<T>() { return new T(); }`, and then you can do `using packet_maker = packet*(*)(); *packet_maker[] array={make<packet>, make<packet1>, make<packet2>, make<packet3> };`

Comment: hmm, the packet maker idea might work.  I like it better than .clone() but I was hoping there would be a similar function pointer type thing for classes

Comment: This sounds like something that can be reasonably handled using simply virtual inheritance and a switch-table or similar selecting among a number of expressions (or lambdas that return a pointer-to-base-class).

Comment: The example of what you want still doesn't justify this. Why do you need a class to read each packet type, and why do you have to clone it in order to read the packet?

Comment: I have to have a class for each packet since each packet has different data.  Since I need a data storage object anyway, I might as well fully use it for reading.  The reason I have to clone it is self obvious, if I didnt clone it I would only have 1 instance to work with and that is clearly unacceptable.

Comment: Nope, none of that is clear to me. Usually with a network communication protocol you read, do what is asked, and then move on. The only time you will store data there is when the stuff you read is incomplete and is pending on subsequent reads to do something with it, but then again, reading this partial data and spreading it across cloned objects does not make any sense at all.

Comment: There's one problem with your understanding.
If you store your packet by interface type, you don't know what is stored inside. You can only call overloaded methods but you can't access anything that is not declared in interface.
You will use different data in different contexts so you still have to branch out execution at some point to handle different data differently.
I assume you store this data because other thread will use it. Otherwise again it does not make sense, your network thread should free all of the data when it's done. Next layer should not be aware of packets at all.

Comment: The packets can change the server state.  There are several read threads that funnel packets to the main thread for execution.  the read threads bundle them in classes so all the main thread has to do is call packet->handle() and the handling is done.  For thread saftey reasons the read threads should not modify the server state on their own.  The partial read for the initial packet is 1 byte, the packet type, all other reading is done by the derived class.

Comment: Yeah they definitively can be stateful, that still doesn't justify keeping them around.

Comment: A class is not an object in C++, unlike some other languages, and doesn't have an address, so can't have pointers to it. And in any case there is no language support for *using* such a pointer. Classic XY problem.

Comment: Oh I see, so the problem is entirely different. The task of reading packets is trivial and does not justify multi-threading, unless you're doing it wrong which seems to be the case. Seems like your reading thread is blocking, because you call `recv()` without checking if there's data first. You should definitively address that.

Comment: Ok, so your packer in reality is more of a task. You read what type of task you want to do, create task, tell it to read incoming data and you put the task to the queue returning back to listening on socket. Other thread gets to the queue and simply executes the task.
I can see only two options. Simple switch statement and task ID defined as enum (you can create task factory hiding it) or map/array from task id to task like you have right now. I would advise to use switch as defining your packet as final you will avoid going through vtable multiple times.

Comment: If this is about creating tasklets then I see where this is going, but then again, you shouldn't mix the packet handling stuff with the creation of those tasks. Those should be entirely separate of one another.

Comment: Proper solution should separate different areas. Task should have access to interface reading data from socket. Task should be created by task factory which can be triggered by your network reader based on read task type. Moreover, your task might not want to read anything, only perform some operation. You should really separate your pocket reader from tasks. What if you have different tasks requiring the same type of data? You'll copy implementation of deserializer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Best answer was never posed as an answer, credit to Raymond Chen

No you can not take a pointer to a class (and are actually forbidden to take the pointer of a constructor http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf 12.1.12), however you can make a pointer to an abject factory by

```cpp
template<typename T> T* make<T>() { return new T(); }
```

and take a function pointer of `make<classToPointTo>`

Much better than my clone function and I didnt want this wonderful answer burred in the comments for the rest of time.

Comment: I don't think it answers question from your topic
```Can you do a pointer to a class in c++?```
Consider updating topic to reflect what you really wanted to achieve.

Comment: I dont see how I would change the topic, to my mind, it answers the question quite adequately, I edited the answer to possibly answer better though

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible this way because types have to be resolved during compilation. You "physically" compile in instruction how to create new objects. Sure, you can make it variable by simple condition based on typeinfo utilizing RTTI.

```
#include <typeinfo>
MyClass *createInstanceOf(const std::type_info& myType)
{
    if (myType == typeid(MyClass))
        return new MyClass();
    if (myType == typeid(MyDerived))
        return new MyDerived();
    // handle invalid type
}
```

This way you can create different objects based on runtime variable (which is variable std::type_info).

```
class MyClass;//real Class
class MyDerived: public MyClass;//derived class
std::type_info myType = typeid(MyClass);//pointer to my class
MyClass * instanceOfPointer = createInstanceOf(myType);//now makes an instance of MyClass
myType = typeid(MyDerived);//pointer to derived class
MyClass * instance2 = createInstanceOf(myType);//now makes an instance of DerivedClass
```

Important part is that this function knows which object creation should be compiled in (all of types you want to support), decision on which path is taken is made in runtime but creation itself is known when you compile the code. Types can never be variable. Even templates are not variable, they generate instances of functions/classes per each type that it was instantiated for during compilation.

I'll add that this solution is useful only in very specific cases. Essentially if you know the type during compilation, then you should never save type_info of the type and then use it in condition to get the type back. It would be much heavier than it should be and is almost impossible to optimize.

Your example seems to be lacking something. As I understand, all you want to do is read type from outside source and then read data based on this variable type. This is quite standard way of reading any outside communication and is done more or less in a way I mentioned above. You need runtime decision mechanism which will take path proper for given type. At some point you'll have to make this decision because your code has to branch out and reach for proper handler (which seems to be packet in your example). 
In this case you should not use typeid as it is only guaranteed to be unique and same for the same type in one execution of program - it can't be shared or stored for next execution. In your case you need your own type information (usually enum is most efficient). This way you can create map of your handlers. If types of packets are known and well defined, then you can make them in order from 0 and store them in regular array with constant access time. That's one of most efficient ways to do this. Essentially it would be your `type.id`.